# What does this mean: 지금 다른 나라는 며칠입니까?

Tags: usage

Google translate says the above sentence means:

> How many days are in other countries?

But I think the person who asks the question was intent to say:

> What date is it now in other countries?

Can Google be so off or the person just asked a wrong question?

What exactly does this means?

> 지금 다른 나라는 며칠입니까?

Comment: 며칠 can mean both how many days and which date. Both translation is correct. You need to judge which depending on what you are talking about before then.

Comment: 며칠 can't mean both in this sentence because of 지금. you don't need to consider what was talked before. Yes, it exactly means "what date is it now in other countries?"

Comment: @Sung Oh, completely overlooked 지금! Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Sung perhaps you could make your comment into an answer? It seems to get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: Wow! Google really missed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes, you're correct.

지금 다른 나라는 며칠입니까? = What date is it now in other countries?

며칠입니까? can mean two

1. 서울**까지** 며칠입니까? (asking how many days it takes to get Seoul)
2. 서울**은** 며칠입니까? (asking what date it is in Seoul)

in this sentence, it asks 다른 나라**는** not 다른나라**까지** so it meant 2.

However, to more clarify, it should be

1. **이곳부터** 서울까지 며칠**걸립니까**?  (이곳부터 서울까지 = from here to Seoul, 걸리다 = take)
2. **오늘** 서울은 며칠입니까?